# XML Loop to match rowset value

Tags: xml, foreach, xsl-fo, rowset

I have an XML Data Sheet that looks like the following. In ROWSET1_ROW, there are a list of ID's. Each ID corresponds to a section of data from ROWSET2_ROW. I am having trouble looping through and matching the ID in ROWSET2_ROW to ROWSET1_ROW. Ultimately, a pdf report will be created that should show three different sections of data. From my loop, I keep getting the first section of ROWSET2_ROW data to print. In other words, I get the first section of ROWSET2_ROW data printed three times (duplicated), which is wrong. I hope I explained that correctly.

```
<DOCUMENT>
<DATA>
<ROWSET1>
  <ROWSET1_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2084</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
</ROWSET1_ROW>
<ROWSET1_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2081</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
</ROWSET1_ROW>
<ROWSET1_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2113</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
</ROWSET1_ROW>
</ROWSET1>
<ROWSET2>
<ROWSET2_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2084</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
  <SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>0018-LAF-01</SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE>Embankment</INSPECTION_FEATURE>
</ROWSET2_ROW><ROWSET2_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2081</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
  <SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>0119-LAF-67</SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE>Sand Boil</INSPECTION_FEATURE>
</ROWSET2_ROW><ROWSET2_ROW>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>2113</INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID>
  <SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>2009-WAC-99</SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID>
  <INSPECTION_FEATURE>Seepage</INSPECTION_FEATURE>
</ROWSET2_ROW>
</DOCUMENT>
</DATA>
```

I have tried the following code, but I keep getting an error --> "fo:flow" is missing child elements. I have tried some variations of this code, like removing the when statement or changing the loop, but if I don't receive the error, I just get the first section or ROWSET2_ROW data printed three times (DUplicated).

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//ROWSET1_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROWSET2_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID">
<xsl:when test="//ROWSET1_ROW//INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID = //ROWSET2_ROW//INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID">
<fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width="3in"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="4.5in"/>



            <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding-top="0.02in">
                  <fo:block>
                    <fo:table>
                      <fo:table-column column-width="1in"/>
                      <fo:table-column column-width="1.85in"/>
                      <fo:table-body>
                      <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell cell-label">
                            <fo:block>
                              Inspection Feature Id
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell" font-weight="bold">
                            <fo:block>
                              <xsl:value-of select="//ROWSET2_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID"/>
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell cell-label">
                            <fo:block>
                              Site Id
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell" font-weight="bold">
                            <fo:block>
                              <xsl:value-of select="//ROWSET2_ROW/SECONDARY_FEATURE_ID"/>
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell cell-label">
                            <fo:block>
                              Feature
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell">
                            <fo:block>
                              <xsl:value-of select="//ROWSET2_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE"/>
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you build the table, the line

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ROWSET2_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID"/>
```

grabs the first match it finds, this is why the rowset2 data is duplicated.

You have to delete the nested for-each:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//ROWSET2_ROW/INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID">
```

The for-each tries to run the loop for every Rowset2 element, but what you really want is to process the Rowset1 elements and add some data to each of those elements.

In the table, you need a statement that says "find the rowset2 data which has an INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID that matches the ID from the node I'm currently processing"

So something along the lines of

```
<xsl:value-of select="sibling::ROWSET2_ROW[INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID = ./INSPECTION_FEATURE_ID]"/>
```

(haven't checked this for syntax)